# Setting Up Maven 3 properly

Tags: java, maven, fedora

How should I set up Maven 3 properly?

My environment:

- Fedora Linux 16;
- Java 1.7.0_22
- Maven 3.0.4

My .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/home/ic/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2_HOME
```

When I type **java -version**, the system shows me

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But when I type **mvn -v**, it shows me:

```
bash: mvn: command not found...
```

What should I do, in order to set up Maven 3 properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19):

Ordering is important!

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/home/ic/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2_HOME

# after the variables are assigned!!!
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: Thank you gareth, it works! I think the problem was ORDERING! o.O

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to config in Ubuntu.

B1: Download Maven and extract at any folder.

EX: thong.tv folder.

B2: Go to file .bashrc, in usual it in directory

EX link : /home/local/thong.tv.

This is a hide file so if you don't see it, you can type Ctrl + H to see.
Open above file go bottom and paste this:

```
MAVEN_HOME="/home/local/thong.tv/apache-maven-3.3.9"
PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_HOME
export PATH
```

B3: Check maven exist. 
Open terminal type:

```
mvn -version
```

You will see like this:

```
thong.tv@java-thongtv:~$ mvn -version Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T23:41:47+07:00)
Maven home: /home/local/SUTRIXMEDIA1/thong.tv/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.10.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Remember: set up jdk before set up Maven.**